# Two questions about OpenStack Swift ring function

Tags: openstack-swift, consistent-hashing

I'm new in Swift and I'm trying to learn its functionality. I have two question for you regarding the ring and the consistent hashing algorithm.

When we want to store an object, we take its path (for example ".../v1/account_name/container_name/object_name.ext"), feed the MD5 hash function with this path, then we obtain an hash value. From this hash value we take the first n bits, where n is the part-power, and use those bits to obtain the partition number. Now, if we access to the ring using the partition number, we can discover in which node that partition is and store the object in this way.

**First question**: what if that partition is full?

Suppose now that swift stores the object in the correct node, the **second question** is: how swift decides where storing the replicas?

Thank you all!

Comment: Can you clarify what do you mean by a partition being full? You mean the disk which has the partition?

Answer (score 0):

> how swift decides where storing the replicas?

When you create a ring informing all nodes and all disks you have for your cluster, it automatically defines where each copy should be and also which handoff nodes to use in case of a failure. So, when you ask the ring where to find/store an object with the hash ABC123DEF... it will answer you something like:

```
Look at here:
SERVER1/DISK2/PATH/TO/FILE
SERVER2/DISK4/PATH/TO/FILE
SERVER4/DISK1/PATH/TO/FILE

And if you don't find, look at here.
Handoff: SERVER2/DISK2/PATH/TO/FILE
Handoff: SERVER8/DISK7/PATH/TO/FILE
Handoff: SERVER3/DISK1/PATH/TO/FILE
```